# IE11/IE10 Compatibility View - Navigation Error

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, authentication

I have a website which has just been designed using twitter bootstrap 3 site and HTML5 but I have an issue in IE11 and IE10 Compatibility as when a user logs in they go through the following process:

1. Enter username and click 'Continue/Enter key' > goes to Password page
2. Enter password and click 'Login/Enter key' > goes to account summary page

The issue is, is that once the password has been validated and is correct, the 'Enter Username' page is re-displayed **BUT** the user is actually logged in as the secure main menu is displayed.

I have tried to de-bug it but nothing is flagged and using F12 also flags no errors except an informational one (HTML1300) but when Googling this, there are no answers for it.

Is there a way to force the site to the correct page (providing password is correct) or anything I can do to stop this happening as a few users are logging this with me when using my site.

As mentioned this is only an issue for IE11 and IE10 Compatibility mode.  Using IE10 (normally) and other browsers is fine.

The code for my view is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Helpers" %>

<%
    var Clientdata = (typeof(AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Entities.LogIn.ClientAdditionalActions) == AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Wrappers.Session.Process.Data.GetType()) ? (AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Entities.LogIn.ClientAdditionalActions)AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Wrappers.Session.Process.Data : null;

    var data = (typeof(AJBG.Web.Services.Messages.User.Authentication.Status.Response) == AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Wrappers.Session.Process.Data.GetType()) ? (AJBG.Web.Services.Messages.User.Authentication.Status.Response)AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Wrappers.Session.Process.Data : null;

    var cmsText = ((AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Translators.LogIn.ChallengeResponse)Model.Data);
    var username = Clientdata != null ? Clientdata.Username : data.Username;
    AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Template content = new AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Template()
        {
            HtmlTemplate = cmsText.Intro_Text
        };

    content.Nvc.Add("[!Password_TextBox]", Html.Password("Password_TextBox", "", new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 30 }).ToHtmlString());
    content.Nvc.Add("[!Password_TextBox_xs]", Html.Password("Password_TextBox_xs", "", new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 30 }).ToHtmlString());
    content.Nvc.Add("[!ErrorMessage]", AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Website.CStr(Html.ValidationMessage("LogInFailure")));
    content.Nvc.Add("[!SubmitButton]", Html.ButtonBootStrap("submit", "btn btn-default", "Login", "Login", "glyphicon glyphicon-lock", "DisableButton(this);").ToHtmlString());
    content.Nvc.Add("[!UserName]", username);
%>

<%using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal", name = "ChallengeForm", id = "ChallengeForm" }))

{ %>
<% 
      if (username.Contains("SCA"))
      {
          Response.Write(cmsText.Adviser_top_text);
      }
      else if (username.Contains("SCC"))
      {
          Response.Write(cmsText.Client_top_text);
      }
%>

<%= content.ToString() %>

<% 
      if (username.Contains("SCA"))
      {
          Response.Write(cmsText.Adviser_bottom_text);
      }
      else if (username.Contains("SCC"))
      {
          Response.Write(cmsText.Client_bottom_text);
      }

} %>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function DisableButton(obj)
    {
        obj.disabled = true;
        <% if (Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer" || Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
        { %>
        if (document.documentMode < 9 || "<%=Request.Browser.Version.ToString()%>" == "7.0")
        {
            ChallengeForm.submit();
        }
        <%}
        else
        {%>
            ChallengeForm.submit();
        <%}%>
        return true;
    }

    if ($(".field-validation-error").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#myModal").remove();
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    }

    if ($("#myModal").is(":visible") == false)
    {
        SetFocus("Password_TextBox");
    }

    $("#Close").on("click", function ()
    {
        SetFocus("Password_TextBox");
    })
</script>
```

And the code behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.User;

namespace AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.ProcessFlow.OriginalLogIn
{
    public class InitialChallenge : ProcessFlow.Base
    {

        #region Private Data vars / objects

        private Web.Services.Messages.User.Authentication.Status.Response _model = null;
        private String _password = String.Empty;
        private String _userName = String.Empty;

        #endregion

        public InitialChallenge(String controller) : base(controller) { }

        public void Setup(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
        }

        public void Form(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            _model      = (Web.Services.Messages.User.Authentication.Status.Response)Wrappers.Session.Process.Data;        
            _password   = HttpContext.Current.Request["Password_TextBox"].ToString();
            _password = String.IsNullOrEmpty(_password) ? HttpContext.Current.Request["Password_TextBox_xs"].ToString() : _password;
            _userName = _model.Username;

            if(Validators.Security.PasswordChallenge(_password,"LoginFailure",modelState))
            {
                String migrateErrormessage = String.Empty;
                String credentialsError = String.Empty;

                #region Credentials Error Check

                switch (_model.Type)
                {
                    case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.OldAdviser:
                        credentialsError = PasswordAdviserCheckBeforeMigration();
                        break;
                    case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.OldClient:
                        credentialsError =PasswordClientCheckBeforeMigration();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                #endregion

                if (credentialsError.Equals(String.Empty))
                {
                    if ((_model.Type == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.Adviser) || (_model.Type == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.OldAdviser))
                    {
                        #region Adviser Log In

                        if (MigrateAdviserAccount(_model.Type, out migrateErrormessage))
                        {
                            //var result = new Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Adviser.AdviserClient().OriginalLogIn
                            //                 (
                            //                       new Web.Services.Messages.Adviser.Authentication.OriginalLogIn.Request
                            //                       {
                            //                           LogInAttemptIdentifier = new Guid(),
                            //                           Username = _model.Username,
                            //                           Password = _password,
                            //                           Source = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre
                            //                       }
                            //                 );

                            // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
                            var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.OriginalLogIn(new Guid(), _model.Username, _password, _model.UserIdentifier);

                            if (result.Details == null)
                            {
                                //Added to account for IFAs Who have just Registered but their details have not quite been populated.
                                if (result.ResponseCode == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.LoginResponseCode.IFA_FIRM_PopulationError)
                                {

                                    AppCode.Wrappers.Session.User.ClearUserData();
                                    Wrappers.Session.Process.StartExiting();
                                    Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "PopulationError");
                                }
                                //will redirect you to account suspended page if password is locked.
                                if (!UserStatusOK()) return;

                                if (Website.MaskError)
                                {
                                    modelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", ErrorMessages.Security.PasswordIncorrect);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    modelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", ErrorMessages.Security.PasswordIncorrect);
                                }

                                modelState.AddModelError("Password_TextBox", "");
                                return;
                            }

                            ProcessAdviserStep(result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            modelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", migrateErrormessage);
                        }


                        #endregion
                    }
                    else if ((_model.Type == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.Client) || (_model.Type == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.OldClient))
                    {
                        #region Client Log In 

                        if (MigrateClientAccount(_model.Type, out migrateErrormessage))
                        {

                            //var result = new Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Client.ClientClient().OriginalLogIn
                            //(
                            //  new Web.Services.Messages.Client.Authentication.OriginalLogIn.Request
                            //     {
                            //         LogInAttemptIdentifier = _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier,
                            //         Password = _password,
                            //         Username = _model.Username,
                            //         Source = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre
                            //     }
                            // );

                            // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
                            var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.ClientLogIn(_model.LogInAttemptIdentifier, _model.Username, _password);

                            if (result.Details == null)
                            {
                                //will redirect you to account suspended page if password is locked.
                                if (!UserStatusOK()) return;

                                modelState.AddModelError("LogInFailure", String.Format(ErrorMessages.Security.AdviserLogInFailure, Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "Entry").Url));
                                modelState.AddModelError("Password_TextBox", "");
                                return;
                            }

                            ProcesClientStep(result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            modelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", migrateErrormessage);
                            modelState.AddModelError("Password_TextBox", "");
                        }

                        #endregion
                    }
                    else { }
                }
                else  
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", credentialsError);
                    modelState.AddModelError("Password_TextBox", "");
                }
            }
        }

        #region Exit

        public override Boolean Exit(ModelStateDictionary modelState, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
        {
            return false;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Migration Methods

        private Boolean MigrateAdviserAccount(Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType account, out String error)
        {
            error = String.Empty;

            if (account == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.OldAdviser)
            {
               // var clientAuthentication = new Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Client.ClientClient();

               // var result = new AccountAdministrationWebService.General.GeneralClient().MigrateAccount(

               //     new Web.Services.Messages.User.Migration.TransferAccount.Request
               //     {

               //         Password = _password,
               //         UserIdentifier = _model.UserIdentifier,
               //         Username = _model.Username,
               //         Source = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre,
               //         PasswordExpired = (Boolean) (_model.Status ==  Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredPassword) 
               //     }
               //);

                // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
                var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.MigrateAccount(_password, 
                    _model.UserIdentifier, 
                    _model.Username, 
                    (Boolean)(_model.Status == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredPassword), 
                    _model.UserIdentifier, _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier);

                error = result.GetErrorMessages();
                return result.Success;
            }


            return (account == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.Adviser) ? true : false;
        }

        private Boolean MigrateClientAccount(Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType account, out String error)
        {
            error = String.Empty;
            if (account == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.OldClient)
            {
               // var clientAuthentication = new Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Client.ClientClient();

               // var result = new AccountAdministrationWebService.General.GeneralClient().MigrateAccount(

               //     new Web.Services.Messages.User.Migration.TransferAccount.Request
               //    {
               //        Password         = _password,
               //        UserIdentifier   = _model.UserIdentifier,
               //        Username         = _model.Username,
               //        Source           = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre,
               //        PasswordExpired  = (Boolean)(_model.Status == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredPassword) 
               //    }
               //);

                // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
                var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.MigrateAccount(_password, 
                            _model.UserIdentifier, 
                            _model.Username, 
                            (Boolean)(_model.Status == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredPassword), 
                            _model.UserIdentifier,
                            _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier); 

                error = result.GetErrorMessages();
                return result.Success;
            }

            return (account == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountType.Client) ? true : false;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Process Step Methods

        private void ProcessAdviserStep(AJBG.Web.Services.Messages.Adviser.Authentication.OriginalLogIn.Response result)
        {
            AppCode.Wrappers.Session.User.ClearUserData();
            AppCode.Wrappers.Session.User.Adviser = result.Details;

            switch (_model.Status)
            {

                case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredSecurityQuestion:
                case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.Active:
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.StartExiting();

                    if (_model.RedirectTo != null && _model.RedirectTo.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var url = AppCode.Functions.Functions.ConvertToVirtualPath(_model.RedirectTo.Split('?')[0]);
                        if (url.StartsWith(AppCode.Wrappers.Application.Area.AdviserExclusive) || !url.StartsWith(AppCode.Wrappers.Application.Area.ClientExclusive))
                        {
                            Wrappers.Session.Process.ForcedRedirect = AppCode.Functions.Functions.ConvertToVirtualPath(_model.RedirectTo.Split('?')[0]) + _model.RedirectTo.Replace(_model.RedirectTo.Split('?')[0], "").Replace("%amp;", "&");
                        }
                    }
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "ExitAdviser");
                    break;
                case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredPassword:
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.Data = new Entities.LogIn.AdviserAdditionalActions
                    {
                        LoginAttemptIdentifier = _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier,
                        Details = result.Details,
                        Status = _model.Status,
                        Username = _model.Username,
                        UserIdentifier = _model.UserIdentifier,

                    };
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "ExpiredPassword");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        private void ProcesClientStep(AJBG.Web.Services.Messages.Client.Authentication.OriginalLogIn.Response result)
        {
            AppCode.Wrappers.Session.User.ClearUserData();
            AppCode.Wrappers.Session.User.Client = result.Details;

            //work out if this is a junior client//
            Boolean isJunior = false;
            if (result.Details.HasIsa)
            {
                if (result.Details.Isa.IsJunior) { isJunior = true; }
            } 
            if (result.Details.HasSipp)
            {
                if (result.Details.Sipp.IsJunior) { isJunior = true; }
            }

            switch (_model.Status)
            {
                case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredSecurityQuestion:
                case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.Active:
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.StartExiting();

                    if ((_model.RedirectTo != null) && (_model.RedirectTo.Length > 0))
                    {
                        var url = AppCode.Functions.Functions.ConvertToVirtualPath(_model.RedirectTo.Split('?')[0]);
                        if (!url.StartsWith(AppCode.Wrappers.Application.Area.AdviserExclusive) || url.StartsWith(AppCode.Wrappers.Application.Area.ClientExclusive))
                        {
                            Wrappers.Session.Process.ForcedRedirect = AppCode.Functions.Functions.ConvertToVirtualPath(_model.RedirectTo.Split('?')[0]) + _model.RedirectTo.Replace(_model.RedirectTo.Split('?')[0], "").Replace("%amp;", "&");
                        }
                    }


                    if (isJunior)
                    {
                        Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "ExitJunior");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "ExitClient");
                    }
                    break;
                case Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.ExpiredPassword:
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.Data = new Entities.LogIn.ClientAdditionalActions
                    {
                        LoginAttemptIdentifier = _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier,
                        Details = result.Details,
                        Status = _model.Status,
                        Username = _model.Username,
                        UserIdentifier = _model.UserIdentifier

                    };
                    Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Situation == "ExpiredPassword");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region PasswordCheckMigration

        public String PasswordAdviserCheckBeforeMigration()
        {
            //Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Adviser.AdviserClient adviserClient = new AccountAdministrationWebService.Adviser.AdviserClient();

            //var result = adviserClient.OldLogIn(new Web.Services.Messages.Adviser.Authentication.OldLogIn.Request
            //{
            //    LogInAttemptIdentifier = _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier,
            //    Password = _password,
            //    Username = _userName,
            //    Source = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre
            //});

            // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
            var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.OldLogin(_model.LogInAttemptIdentifier, _userName, _password);

            //adviserClient.Close();

            if (result.Success)
            {
                if (result.ErrorMessages.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Website.MaskError)
                    {
                        if (result.ResponseCode == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.LoginResponseCode.CredentialsFailed)
                            return ErrorMessages.Security.PasswordIncorrect;
                        else
                            return Log.MaskErrors(result.ResponseCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return result.GetErrorMessages();
                    }
                }
            }

            return String.Empty;
        }

        public String PasswordClientCheckBeforeMigration()
        {

                //Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Client.ClientClient clientClient = new Sippcentre.AccountAdministrationWebService.Client.ClientClient();
                //var result = clientClient.OldLogIn(new Web.Services.Messages.Client.Authentication.OldLogIn.Request
                //{
                //    LogInAttemptIdentifier = _model.LogInAttemptIdentifier,
                //    Password = _password,
                //    Username = _userName,
                //    Source = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre
                //});
                //clientClient.Close();

                // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
                //var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin._OldLogin(_model.LogInAttemptIdentifier, _userName, _password);

                // The login process is no different in case of old users . The users will still be avalable in WebUser table 
                var result = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.ClientLogIn(_model.LogInAttemptIdentifier, _userName, _password);

                if (result.Success)  {
                 if (result.ErrorMessages.Count > 0)
                 {
                    if (Website.MaskError)
                    {
                        if (result.ResponseCode == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.LoginResponseCode.CredentialsFailed)
                            return ErrorMessages.Security.PasswordIncorrect;
                        else
                            return Log.MaskErrors(result.ResponseCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return result.GetErrorMessages();
                    }
                }
               }

            return String.Empty;
        }


        #endregion

        #region check Status 

        private Boolean UserStatusOK()
        {
            Boolean statusOK = true;

            //var accountStatus = new AccountAdministrationWebService.General.GeneralClient().CheckUserStatus(new Web.Services.Messages.User.Authentication.Status.Request
            //{
            //    Username = _userName,
            //    RequestByIdentifier = _userName,
            //    Source = Web.Services.Messages.Enums.MessageSource.Sippcentre
            //});

            // *********** ENTITY WRAPPER CALL
            var accountStatus = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.EntityWrappers.AccountAdmin.CheckUserStatus(_userName, _userName);

            if (accountStatus.Status == Web.Services.Messages.Enums.AccountStatus.Suspended)
            {
                Wrappers.Session.Process.Data = null;
                Wrappers.Session.Process.Step = Steps.First(d => d.Situation == "ResponseSuspended");
                statusOK = false;
            }

            return statusOK;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think we might need to see some code in order to identify the issue ?

Comment: @Bartdude Code added

Comment: Wow that's a shitload of code you're posting... You might want to narrow it down a bit by stripping the part that have for sure nothing to do with your problem. That said I already found a possible source : `if (document.documentMode < 9 || "<%=Request.Browser.Version.ToString()%>" == "7.0")`. Indeed, `documentMode` might be different on a "real" IE and on a compatibility mode. I would first have a look at this if I were you. If other parts of your code include that kind of test on the browser, those would be the parts you want to debug.

Comment: Bootstrap explicitly doesn't attempt to support Compatibility Views: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie-compatibility-modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon investigation, it is because IE11 now comes back as Mozilla hence why it wasn't hitting my code.  by adding `Majorverion > 10` to the following line has fixed the issue for me

```
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer" || Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || Majorverion > 10
```

Hope this helps other people